# C# application It still visible in Task Manager after exit

Tags: c#, winforms, exit

I am currently debugging a C# Windows form application. I am exiting application through `Application.Exit()`
But It still shows on the Task Manager and weird thing is that I am not able to terminate it either. The only way is to reboot.

Comment: Is it YourAppName.vshost.exe?  That's a process Visual Studio keeps alive between runs, but it's not actually your application.  Or are you using multiple threads that are not marked as background threads?

Comment: @adv12 It shows app.exe and app.vshost.exe but I am not able to kill app.exe and I am using multiple threads but that I Have to check whether It's background property is true or false.

Comment: @chinkalpanchal Indeed check your threads. They all must be `IsBackground = true`, otherwise as mentioned in the documentation will keep your app from terminating.

Comment: "weird thing is that I am not able to terminate it either" -- How are you trying to terminate it using task manager? Are you on the Applications tab, then right clicking and going to "End Task", or are you on the Processes tab and right clicking and going to "End Process"? If the process doesn't exit using Processes Tab->End Process then you likely created an unkillable situation by creating a deadlock with the Windows kernel. I believe you can still End Process the case @IvanStoev mentioned (IsBackground = false), that case should only make End Task not work.

Comment: @quantic @adv12 I'll make sure that `IsBackground = true` in all the threads.

Answer (score 1):

Go to project properties, navigate to the Debug section and deselect "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".

Next time you perform a debug it should clear out the process.